# AWS ELB Intermittent 502 gateway timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an ELB in front of a node.js application deployed on 3 EC2 instances.

I have started **observing intermittent HTTP 502 Bad Gateway error**.

Following is an excerpt from my access logs. There is no pattern to these 502 errors so I am unable to narrow down the cause ?

Is it an `ELB` issue or an app issue ?

Can access logs help me figure this out ?

This occurs for 5 requests in every 100 requests

```
*type*                     https    
*timestamp*                2019-05-08T14:50:11.438405Z  
*elb*                      <my-elb>
*client:port*              clientIp:port
*target:port*              targetIp:port
*request_processing_time*  0    
*target_processing_time*.  2.596    
*response_processing_time* -1   
*elb_status_code*          502  
*target_status_code*       -    
*received_bytes*           792  
*sent_bytes*               293  
*request*                  POST https://app/app-url/2.0/resourcepath/id/abc?queryParamA=abc&queryParamB=false&queryParamC=6b84c34 HTTP/1.1  
*user_agent*               Apache-CXF/3.2.5 
*ssl_cipher*               ssl-cipher
*ssl_protocol*             TLSv1.2  
*target_group_arn*         arn
*trace_id*                 traceId
*domain_name*              cool-domain-name
*chosen_cert_arn*          session-reused   
*matched_rule_priority*    0    
*request_creation_time*    2019-05-08T14:50:08.841000Z  
*actions_executed*         forward  
*redirect_url*             -    
*error_reason*             -
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure your node server keepAliveTimeout is greater than the ELB idle timeout. ELB and ALB don't like when the target machine closes the connection. To detect this you can check the elb logs, you may see response time of -1 with 502. '-1' means the target did a direct reject of the request.

Comment: Other resources that helped me are https://adamcrowder.net/posts/node-express-api-and-aws-alb-502/ and https://www.transposit.com/blog/2018.09.14-mysterious-case/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference link to start with: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-502-issues

The most common among them is the backend keep-alive is less then the ELB , ELB keeps the connection open while backend has closed it and when ELB uses the same TCP connection, it gets RESET.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you're not using Apache's event MPM module (default) when behind a ALB/ELB. It dynamically closes connections. Try worker MPM.

Comment: This was the issue for me, but running a PHP app I had to use PHP-FPM instead of worker MPM.

Answer (score 0):

A 502 on an ELB generally points to an app/server issue. The ELB is having problems communicating with the app server.  Check the app logs for restarts or other errors.

Per the RFC:

> **10.5.3 502 Bad Gateway**
>   The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server it accessed in attempting to fulfill the request.

Possible causes are empty or incomplete headers or response body, caused by broken connections. Look for 500 server errors in the app log also.

In your case,  an app server crash can cause 502 errors on the ELB.

See

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 0):

Check you target group and make sure that the health checks works fine. In our case, we had a broken health check, that marked all nodes as Unhealthy. We have auto-scaling so nodes would be added/removed from the group dynamically (depending on the current load).

Then this bizarre behaviour of the AWS Load Balancer kicked in (from the official docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/elb-ag.pdf):

> If there is at least one healthy target in a target group, the load balancer routes requests only to the healthy targets. If a target group contains only unhealthy targets, the load balancer routes requests to the unhealthy targets.

Because of this beahviour we didn't realize the health checks were broken, and the 502s happened requests were routed to nodes that were just being added/removed to/from the target group. Fixing the health check fixed the issue.