# ALB gives target_status_code as - (hyphen)

Tags: amazon-web-services, gunicorn, aws-application-load-balancer, http-status-code-502

I have my application hosted in AWS. And I have a python application running on the ECS using gunicorn web server and the ECS is behind the load balancer (ALB). The issue that I'm facing is, I get a 502 Gateway error often from ALB. When I checked the logs, it has - (hyphen) in the place of the `target_status_code` column.

According to [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html), the following is the description for this field,

> target_status_code:
> The status code of the response from the target. This value is
> recorded only if a connection was established to the target and the
> target sent a response. Otherwise, it is set to -.

But when I checked the target groups, it doesn't look like there are any connection issues.

I use the following command to start the gunicorn workers,

```
gunicorn \
-c gunicorn_config.py \
-b 0.0.0.0:5000 aiohttp_wsgi_handler:aioapp \
-k aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker \
-w 3 \
--access-logfile - \
--access-logformat '%t [INFO] %P request_id=%{X-REQUEST-ID}o cf_id=%{X-Amz-Cf-Id}i %r %s %b %Tfs' \
--log-level debug \
--graceful-timeout 180
```

Also, I checked the application logs, the request that I made hasn't reached the application.

What could be the cause for this?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I'm not getting the above issue every time. I get it very occasionally.

Answer (score 1):

it's probably link to this : [AWS ELB Intermittent 502 gateway timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370368/aws-elb-intermittent-502-gateway-timeout-error/60402369#60402369) specially if the request time is 0 and backend time is -1 . It means the remote server dropped the socket right before ALB detected it and when an incoming connection was arriving. May be worth checking timeout setting on backend to make sure it's higher than the ALB keep alive.

Answer (score 0):

`target_status_code` is recorded only when there is a successful connection to the target, and hence receives a response from the target. Otherwise it is recorded as `-`.